# Importing JS classes into Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, html5-canvas

Im pretty inexperienced with Vue JS and Nuxt JS but I am working on a project that requires me to import JS sketches. Tbh I am really struggling with understanding how I can import and declare a class instance in Nuxt JS (Vue).

The original JS sketch can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/olearyb/jxk1ey8r/5/

I am trying to export the class Blob and import it into Vue JS.

[Screenshot VueJS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKhsa.png)

However, I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

```
<script>
import Blob from "../assets/content/Blob_Point" 
export default {
  created() {
   new Blob("#C09EFF")
   },
}
</script>
```

However I am getting errors on some of the variables within the Blob class, for example:

26:9   error  'radius' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars

However, the radius is set within the original JS class to this._radius or 300.

Again, I am completely new to VueJS and have only a little bit of experience in JS.

Appreciate any help or direction!

Comment: This is a lint warning about an unused variable. Either the variable or ignore/reconfigure your linter to tolerate it.

Comment: This is not Vue or Nuxt problem. You are using ESLint (basic Nuxt project installs it), and it's set to lint your code - it validates certain coding patterns/styles and emits warning or errors if they are not kept. ESLint: https://eslint.org/, ESLint plugin Vue: https://eslint.vuejs.org/, and some Nuxt setup ideas: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/development-tools/#eslint-and-prettier and a way to disable this linting: https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is from ESLint. You can run

```
yarn lint --fix
```

or

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

to auto fix all the linting issues or you can set that specific file  to be ignore by ESLint